# "discord not defined" while using vscode and powershell

Tags: javascript, powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm quite new to *javascript*, and while trying to connect *discord* and *VSCode* (using *windows powershell*) I'm using this

```js
    const Discord = require (discord.js) ;
    const client = new Discord.Client();

    client.once;ready ; () => {
    console.log ;Ready ; 
    };

    client.login (discord-bot-token);
```

and if you can't tell, I'm trying to make a discord bot. But when trying to run `node index.js` on *powershell* I keep getting the error `discord is not defined` as in discord.js. And I do have the bot token in there just don't really want to give that away.

Answer (score 1):

`const Discord = require("discord.js");`

the require statement should have a string as an argument. Also, make sure you have the right path to discord.js

For example if you have it in a different directly like libs you have to write

`const Discord = require ("./libs/discord.js") ;`